# Unable to remote debug Chrome on ASUS Transformer Android tablet

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, remote-debugging

I'm following this guide:  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

However, when I get to the step that says:

> On your device, an alert prompts you to allow USB debugging from your computer. Tap OK.

I never get that alert on my device. (USB debugging IS enabled)

If I go to chrome://inspect on my desktop I can see my device listed there, but there are no options under it, nothing that I can click on.

[image: No device options]

Comment: I feel like it might be a driver issue.  However, the only download on the ASUS support page is their "ASUS Sync" application.  I have installed that and it works.
http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=ASUS+Transformer+Pad+TF300T&os=8

Comment: also, I have tried switching between connecting as MTP and connecting as PTP, and it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: I've tried downloading the driver and installing it manually from this link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1697227 but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

this is my issue too , and over spending 2 hours , I fnally fixed that .

> 1. Go to http://adbdriver.com/downloads/ download and check if your adb driver is install right or not ? If wrong , please reinstall it.
> 2. Access to C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools ,
>      **open cmd** from here ( Shift + right click) and type : **adb devices** . You should see a device in the list.
> 3. Back to your chrome://inspect/#devices and you will see your devices ready for inspect .